# Moon surface 3D print model (DEMto3D plugin) - STL not generated

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, 3d-model, moon

I am trying to create a 3D `.stl` model of the Moon's surface for printing. I am using the DEM `.tif` file from USGS: https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Moon/LRO/LOLA/ancillary/LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPolar875_10m.tif

I've imported the file as a Raster Layer into QGIS:

[image]

I was even able to create a 3D projection of surface with the use of Qgis2threejs:

[image]

After that, I wanted to use plugin DEMto3D in order to generate the `.stl` file. However, when I open the DEM 3D printing window, I am unable to determine the Model height, as, according to QGIS, lowest and highest points of the model are both 0 meters. Because of that, I can't create STL:

[image]

Also, after entering any value in the **Model size** section (for example Spacing) I am getting Python error which goes as follows:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/Kamil0232/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DEMto3D\DEMto3D_Dialog\DEMto3D_dialog.py", line 698, in upload_size_from_width
    width_roi = self.rect_Params["width"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

[image]

How can I convert this `.tif` file to `.stl` which I could print? If the Qgis2threejs was able to generate 3D model, I assume, that it should be also possible with DEMto3D. What am I doing wrong. I am using QGIS 3.30.0.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem turned out to be the version of the QGIS. After switching from 3.30.0 (which is still under development) to 3.28.0, everything works fine. There are no errors, Model height properties are correct and `.stl` file is generated.

[image]